# The Lie exponential map coincides with the matrix exponential?

Tags: lie-groups, lie-algebras, matrix-exponential, linear-groups

From the wikipedia:

> If $G$ is a matrix Lie group, then the exponential map coincides with the matrix exponential.

Is there any proof of this? I searched and did not find any. I failed to prove it myself.

Comment: The chapter 3 of this can be useful: https://www.math.stonybrook.edu/~kirillov/mat552/liegroups.pdf

Comment: Hint: First work out the case of $GL(n,R)$, more precisely, the subgroup of diagonal matrices. Also https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/99545/proof-matrix-exponential-maps-from-tangent-space-to-matrix-lie-group?rq=1

Answer (score 4):

Let $\mathfrak g$ be the Lie algebra of $G$. It turns out that$$\mathfrak{g}=\left\{X\in\mathfrak{gl}(n,\mathbb{R})\,\middle|\,(\forall t\in\mathbb{R}):\exp(tX)\in G\right\}.$$Now, let $X\in\mathfrak{g}$. Consider the map$$\begin{array}{rccc}\gamma_X\colon&\mathbb R&\longrightarrow&G\\&t&\mapsto&\exp(tX).\end{array}$$Then $\gamma_X$ is a Lie group homomorphism from $(\mathbb{R},+)$ into $G$ such that ${\gamma_X}'(0)=X$. Therefore, by definition, $\exp_G(X)=\gamma_X(1)=\exp(X)$.