# Find the tangent space of $\mathrm{Aff}(n)$

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, lie-groups, affine-geometry

Find the tangent space of $\mathrm{Aff}(n)$.

see [Proof: Tangent space of the general linear group is the set of all squared matrices](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/99009/proof-tangent-space-of-the-general-linear-group-is-the-set-of-all-squared-matri)

$\mathrm{Aff}(n)$ is the set of all matrices of the form 
 $$     \begin{pmatrix}
        A & \ b \\
        0 & 1 \\
        \end{pmatrix}$$ where A $\in GL_n(\mathbb{R})$, b in $\mathbb{R}^n$, and $0$ is $1 \times n$ zero vector

Let   $$    1 =  \begin{pmatrix}
        I & \ 0 \\
        0 & 1 \\
        \end{pmatrix}$$

where I is identity matrix and 0 is a 0 column vector.

So my path is Q(t)  $$     \begin{pmatrix}
        A(t) & \ bt \\
        0 & 1 \\
        \end{pmatrix}$$ where $A(t)$ is a path in $ GL_n(\mathbb{R})$ s.t $A(0) = I$.

Comment: There's no reason for the path to be in $Aff(n)$. For example you could have $Q = -I$

Comment: I need the path to be in Aff(n). By the way -I is in Aff(n).

Comment: Yes, but the path isn't: at $t = 1/2$.

Comment: alright thanks, how could I make such a path? 
Why did you mention that the path doesnt need to be in Aff(n)?

Comment: I mentioned this because you asked in the question "I am not sure if this path is in Aff(n)? i.e. Is determinant of tA + (1-t)I not equal to zero?" The answer is: it is not necessarily in Aff(n).

Comment: Alright, do you know a path such that A(t) is in Aff(n) s.t A(0) = 1 and A(1) = Q? thanks

Comment: If your $Q$ has negative determinant, there can be no such path. $GL(n,\Bbb R)$ has two components.

Comment: What do you mean " two components" ?

Comment: @sarah He means two connected components in the topological sense. The determinant gives a continuous group homomorphism from $GL(n,\mathbb R) \to \mathbb R^\times$. Taking pre-images of the positive and negative connected components of $\mathbb R^\times$ gives you the two components of the general linear group.

Answer (score 3):

Continuing from where you were:

$$\forall A:(-\epsilon,\epsilon) \to \operatorname{GL}_n(\mathbb R), A(0) = \operatorname{id}_n$$
$$\forall b \in \mathbb{R}^n$$ Define $Q :(-\epsilon,\epsilon) \to \operatorname{Aff}_n(\mathbb R)$ $$Q(t) =\begin{pmatrix}
        A(t) & \ bt \\
        0 & 1 \\
        \end{pmatrix}$$

Finding the tangent space at the identity means finding the tangent vectors to all possible curves at the identity. Thus, we differentiate and evaluate at $0$. $$\dot Q(t) =\begin{pmatrix}
        \dot A(t) & \ b \\
        0 & 0 \\
        \end{pmatrix}$$
 $$\dot Q(0) =\begin{pmatrix}
        \dot A(0) & \ b \\
        0 & 0 \\
        \end{pmatrix} \in \mathfrak{aff}(n) $$ 
$$\implies \mathfrak{aff}(n) =  \left\{ \begin{pmatrix}
        M & \ b \\
        0 & 0 \\
        \end{pmatrix} \ \middle|\ M \in \operatorname{Mat}_n(\mathbb R),b \in \mathbb{R}^n \right\}$$

Thus we find that $b$ is arbitrary, and varying $A$ over the general linear group gives us all possible matrices in $\mathfrak{gl}_n(\mathbb R) = \operatorname{Mat}_n(\mathbb R)$.

Then as vector spaces, $\mathfrak{aff}_n(\mathbb R) = \mathfrak{gl}_n(\mathbb R) \oplus \mathbb R ^n $. As Lie algebras, you have to take the [semi-direct product of the two terms](http://www.math.kochi-u.ac.jp/docky/bourdoki/NAS/nas006/node21.html), which in this case is just a way of saying the direct sum of the two as vector spaces has the bracket operation defined on it in the natural way.